# gSOAP: how to compile code generated with wsdl2h and soapcpp2

Tags: c++, compilation, gsoap

I'm trying to do some experiments with the [gSOAP 2.8 platform](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

I'd need some help to compile the code generated with the [wsdl2h and soapcpp2](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapmain.html#howto) tools.

After running the two tools:
bin\win32\wsdl2h.exe -v -t typemap.dat -s -o myTests\out.h file.wsdl
bin\win32\soapcpp2 -2 -C -dmyTests\ -Iimport;custom myTests\out.h

I get 5 files soapC.cpp, soapClient.cpp, soapClientLib.cpp, soapH.h, soapStub.h

My problem is that I don't know where to find the correct stdsoap2.h file to use to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found in gsoap-2.8\gsoap folder.