# I can't generate stdsoap2.c (.h) file with soapcpp2 release 2.8.117

Tags: c, gsoap

I am following tutorials on gSOAP [website](https://www.genivia.com/tutorials.html) to build a gSOAP-based web service. Specifically, I follow an example for building this service using `calc.c` from the auto-generated `calc.h`. I have run the following commands in Ubuntu.

```
wsdl2h -c -o calc.h http://www.genivia.com/calc.wsdl
soapcpp2 -CL calc.h
cc -o calc calc.c soapClient.c soapC.c stdsoap2.c
```

The second command, `soapcpp2 -CL calc.h`, is supposed to generate files required for the compilation of a gSOAP-based application.

The problem is that the file `stdsoap2.c` is not generated and I could not figure out the problem.

I tried to re-install the `gsoap` package and run the commands again, but it did not generate the `stdsoap2.c` file.

I read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818254/gsoap-how-to-compile-code-generated-with-wsdl2h-and-soapcpp2), but I could not locate the gsoap directory in ubuntu. So, I copied the `stdsoap2.c` and `stdsoap2.h` files from another project and pasted them into mine, which happened to pass this error. Then I had another error that `calc.c` was not generated, and something about the gsoap version.

```
cc1: fatal error: calc.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from soapH.h:16,
                 from soapClient.c:18:
soapStub.h:20:3: error: #error "GSOAP VERSION 208117 MISMATCH IN GENERATED CODE VERSUS LIBRARY CODE: PLEASE REINSTALL PACKAGE"
   20 | # error "GSOAP VERSION 208117 MISMATCH IN GENERATED CODE VERSUS LIBRARY CODE: PLEASE REINSTALL PACKAGE"
      |   ^~~~~
In file included from soapH.h:16,
                 from soapC.c:19:
soapStub.h:20:3: error: #error "GSOAP VERSION 208117 MISMATCH IN GENERATED CODE VERSUS LIBRARY CODE: PLEASE REINSTALL PACKAGE"
   20 | # error "GSOAP VERSION 208117 MISMATCH IN GENERATED CODE VERSUS LIBRARY CODE: PLEASE REINSTALL PACKAGE"
      |   ^~~~~
```

How to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdsoap2.c` and `stdsoap2.h` represent the *library* code. These files will not be generated by `wsdl2h` or `soapcpp2`.

Placing a copy of these files in the project is a very manual way of including the library. To make this work you must ensure that the version of the library code matches that of generated code.

- Invoking `soapcpp2 -V` (and/or `wsdl2h -V`) will tell you the version of the generated code.
- `grep GSOAP_VERSION stdsoap2.h` will tell you the version of the library you copied.

You have a version mismatch between the generated code and the library (the files you copied), hence the error.

On Ubuntu, you are better off using the package manager.

While the [`gsoap`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gsoap) package contains the tools for code generation, the [`libgsoap-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgsoap-dev) package contains the [*development* files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libgsoap-dev/filelist) needed to compile your final program.

```bash
$ apt install libgsoap-dev
```

<sup>(*Note: [`libgsoap`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgsoap-2.8.117), which contains the runtime libraries, will be installed as a dependency for both `gsoap` and `libgsoap-dev`.*)</sup>

Compile your [program](https://www.genivia.com/files/calc.c), *linking* against the `gsoap` library:

```bash
$ cc -o calc calc.c soapClient.c soapC.c -lgsoap
```

```bash
$ ./calc add 40 2
result = 42
```